# How do I make a C# user control property data bindable?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, mvvm, dependency-properties

I have a MVVM Windows Phone 8 app.  The XAML page has a *user control* that I created that needs to be notified when a change takes place in the **View Model**.  To facilitate this, I created an *int* property in the *user control* to be bound to a property in the **View Model**, so the *user control* property's *setter* method would be triggered when the property it was bound to in the **View Model** changed.

Using the code below, the *user control's* **VideosShownCount** property does show up in the *Property List* at design-time but when I click on the binding mini-button, the *Create Data Binding* option is *greyed out* in the pop-up menu.

So I have one or two questions, depending on what is the root problem:

1) How do I make a property in a **View Model** available as a Data Binding source?

2) How do I format a *user control* property so the IDE allows it to be data bound to a **View Model** property?

```
    private int _videosShownCount = 0;

    public int VideosShownCount 
    { 
        get
        {
            return this._videosShownCount;
        }
        set
        {
            this._videosShownCount = value;
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VideoShownCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("VideosShownCount", typeof(int), typeof(MyUserControl), 
        new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(VideoShownCountPropertyChanged))); 

    static void VideoShownCountPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyUserControl MyUserUserControl = (MyUserControl)sender;

        // Don't care about the value, just want the notification.
        // int val = (int)e.NewValue;

        // Do work now that we've been notified of a change.
        MyUserUserControl.DoWork();
    }
```

Comment: It is always best to type 'propdp' and then hit tab when creating Dependency Properties

Comment: @ShawnKendrot - good tip.  Any ideas on why I'm having the data binding problem?

Comment: Dunno, I create a new UserControl, added a new dp MyProperty (just used all of the defaults except for ownerType), compiled, added the control to a Grid in a PhoneApplicationPage, and Create Data Binding is enabled.

Comment: @ShawnKendrot Do you set the Data Context explicitly in the user control?

Comment: Not in the sample app i used. It was set in the ctor after InitializeComponent

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the `DependencyProperty` for your property, which will definitely cause problems between your code and the bindings

```
public int VideosShownCount
{
    get { return (int) GetValue(VideosShownCountProperty); }
    set { SetValue(VideosShownCountProperty, value); }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the main cause of your problem, but it's worth fixing regardless.

Comment: Thanks.  Made the changes but still no luck.

Comment: you also have to mark your property with [Browsable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx) and [EditorBrowsable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx) attributes if you want to make it visible in the designer

Comment: @Daedalus The property is showing the designer, available for editing.  But as I said, when I pop-up the binding menu, the Create Data Binding  option is disabled.  I tried adding those two attributes anyways, and it didn't help: [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]